# angular 2 and stomp: Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, stomp, sockjs

I keep having and error, and have seen that

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DataComponent

I don't know how I can debug it either where it comes from. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

> Datacomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { Message, Client, Stomp } from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

@Component({
    selector: 'data',
    template: `
        <div id="raw">
            <h2>Messages</h2>
            <p>{{message}}</p>
        </div>
        `,
})
export class DataComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private client : Client) { }

    mq_username = "guest";
    mq_password = "guest";
    mq_vhost    = "/";
    mq_url      = 'http://localhost:15674/stomp';
    mq_queue    = "/exchange/helloworld";

    public message: string;

     /** Callback on_connect to queue */
    public on_connect = () => {
        console.log('client', this.client);
        this.client.subscribe(this.mq_queue, function(message: Message) {
            this.message = message.body; 
        })
    }
    public on_connect_error(){
        console.log('connection failed');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.client = Stomp.client(this.mq_url);
        this.client.connect(
            this.mq_username,
            this.mq_password,
            this.on_connect,
            this.on_connect_error,
            this.mq_vhost
        )
    }
}
```

In the `tsconfig.ts` option both `emitDecoratorMetadata` and `experimentalDecorators` are set to true.

And in `systemjs.config` libraries are included this way :

```
 System.config({
    paths: {
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      app: 'dist',

      // angular bundles
      [ANGULAR BUNDLES HERE]

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'sockjs-client': 'lib/sock-js/sockjs.min.js',
      'stompjs': 'node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp.min.js',
    },
    [etc]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Client is not an angular 2 service.

If that is the case, then you cannot inject it through the constructor.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/sjmf/ng2-stompjs-demo) it uses an earlier version angular 2 but it should give you an idea on how to make it work.

Comment: I'll try to inject it as a service and get back with and update. Thanks a lot for the hint.

Comment: When using this example I get an error like `core.umd.js:3462 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL's scheme must be either 'ws' or 'wss'. 'http' is not allowed.` 
@Meireles How can I allow HTTP scheme ?